# How to create timer in c++

Tags: c++, timer

Two independent timers with two different time periods running simultaneously. 
Using `SetWaitableTimer`.

```
SetWaitableTimer(mhandle, &liDueTime, 0, onCallFunc, this, TRUE);
```

What iperiod indicate?

Answer (score 0):

After the first timer expiry at `lpDueTime`, the timer will go off every `lPeriod` milliseconds unless

- `lPeriod` is zero. Zero means the timer goes off only once, or
- `lPeriod` is less than zero. `SetWaitableTimer` fails if given a negative period.

For more details see [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-setwaitabletimer).